# Hibernate using Generatornames multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate

we are currently migrating from MSSQL to Oracle and we dont want to use the hibernate_sequence for all tables. Each table should have its own Sequence.

We already did the change in our testenvironment but I'd like to get some additional info if our solution is safe to use..

Most of our classes are extending from baseentities but we also have a couple of stand-alone entities.

What we changed:

```
-baseentities(@MappedSuperclass):   
changed: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)   
to: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "HIBERNATE_GENERATOR")
```

-extending entities:

```
added after the @Table annotation:  
@SequenceGenerator(name = "HIBERNATE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "${TABLENAME}_SEQ")
```

-stand-alone entities:
added after the @Table annotation:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "HIBERNATE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "${TABLENAME}_SEQ")
changed : @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)   
to: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "HIBERNATE_GENERATOR")
```

So we are using always the same generatorname "HIBERNATE_GENERATOR", only the sequenceNames are different.
Our applications seems to work fine, but is it safe to use always the same generatorname?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe. My guess is that all your generated values are generated by the same sequence. Indeed, the javadoc says:

> Defines a primary key generator that may be referenced by name when a generator element is specified for the GeneratedValue annotation. A sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the primary key field or property. **The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit (across all generator types)**.

(emphasis mine)

Each entity should define its own generator.

Comment: actually a look in the db shows that each sequence generates the id's on its own.. maybe the global change was in a later version of hibernate?

Comment: That behavior is not defined by Hibernate, but by JPA. Maybe Hibernate doesn't respect the spec here, but I wouldn't rely on this misbehavior, and stick to what the spec says.

Comment: Mh ok, how would you do the change then? Changing the stand-alone entities is no problem. But the mappedsuperclasses and extending classes... my idea would be to move the annotation from the field to the getID() method in the baseentities and then override it with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "${Table}_GENERATOR") in the extending classes. Should that work?

Comment: That would change the access mode of your entities, and would force to put all annotations on getters. Why not simply define the ID in the subclass?